# How to generate a 4 distinct digit random number in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand( time(NULL) );
    int number = (rand() % 9000)+1000;
    cout<<number<<endl;
}
```

This code helps in generating a 4 digit number but not a distinct one i.e it generates numbers like 4545 , 1561 ,9999 etc.. whereas I want numbers like 1234  ,2395 etc...

Comment: Why don't you just generate several numbers until you see one with different digits?

Comment: **Recommended reading: *[Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)***

Comment: I am working on a game Bulls and Cows, it needs only distinct digit random numbers to be generated

Comment: Yes, we understood the question. What do you think of Alex's suggestion, Tyler?

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0: Theoretically, that could take infinite time ;)

Comment: it's called a permutation. Just generate the list of digit you want, and randomly swap two (do it N times)

Comment: I will not be able to see the number and yeah infinite time thing too...@alexeykuzmin0

Answer (score 1):

You could roll numbers until you get one with distinct digits, but that would be extremely inefficient.

You can either:

- generate the first digit, and then
- generate each next digit until it is different from the previous ones
- put all digits together to form the number

or (more efficient):

- roll a number between 0-9 for the first digit `d1`
- roll a number between 0-8 for the second digit `d2` , if `d2>=d1` then set `d2 += 1`
- roll a number between 0-7 for the third digit, etc...

Comment: I think the third digit may be same as first if we follow the second approach(efficient)

Comment: well the algorithm as written in the answer isnt complete. For the third number you have to `+=1` it if it is `>=d1` and `+=1` if it is `>=d2` and these checks and increments actually have to be done in increasing order of the digits. I didnt want to go to much into detail, but just wrote the general idea. SO isnt a code writing service after all :P

Comment: haha yes, fine then ...Thanks